# Is `humanized policy` or `human-centered policy` idiomatic English?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In Chinese context, sometimes people want to refer some policies that designed with the considering for citizens involved(for example, to reduce bureaucratic complexity). The closest translation I found is "humanized policy", or "human-centered policy". But I haven't found many usages from Google search. Is this idiomatic usage in English? Or is it because in the English-speaking world there is no such a concept?

Answer (score 2):

"human-centered policy" seems idiomatic to me and perfectly fine.

> Human-Centered Policymaking — putting human needs and real human behavior. at the center of rulemaking and testing iteratively implementations of rules—can. make government work better. [Source](https://www.belfercenter.org/sites/default/files/2020-04/HumanPolicyMaking.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Human-centered policy-making** seems to be a thing, based on Google results. Certainly **human-centered design** is a real discipline.